# "BY" as an Adverb

Tags: grammar, adverbs

sentences where 'by' is used as an adverb:

> He just passed **by**.
>
> He had already gone **by**.

I know the only one use of **by** as an Adverb, ie, the above.
INTERNET didn't help me enough.

Please explain.

Thank you.

Comment: Trad grammar analyses "by" as an adverb, but it's best analysed as a preposition, more precisely a stranded preposition (the kind that is missing its complement).

Answer (score 1):

Adverbs describe the action (verbs). What is by describing here? passed? gone?
I am not an expert in grammar but in these sentences, I see "by" as a preposition that is connecting the pronoun "he" and the verbs and is not describing the action "passed" or "gone".

Answer (score 0):

In the sentences you mentioned, “by” means “passing a point near something” or “past”. Besides this, “by” as an adverb has two other meanings.

Near

> The house is close by.

Away or aside

> He put some money by each week for savings.